# Como poner una matricula en java segura

Tags: java

Hola tengo que hacer matrícula (estará compuesta por 4 números consecutivos seguido de 3 letras también consecutivas, sin espacios en blanco entre números y letras). Y quiero un metodo que reciba un string matricula y compruebe que tiene un formato adecuado

Yo he hecho,

```
 private final String matricula ="1111AAA";
```

¿Así estaría bien? o ¿crearíais un método?

Comment: Hola @bpico. No esta claro lo que se pregunta. Exactamente, ¿Qué quieres hacer con esa matrícula?

Comment: ¿la pregunta entonces es si se crearía un método?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar una expresión regular:

> `^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}$`

Significa que solo admite 4 digitos (`[0-9]{4}`) seguidos de 3 letras (`[A-Z]{3}`)

```
boolean comprobarMatricula (String matricula){

    if (matricula.toUpperCase().matches("^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}$")) {
        System.out.println("Matrícula válida");
        return true;

    }else{

        System.out.println("Matrícula inválida");
        return false;
    }      
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué `[0-9]` en lugar de `\d`?

Comment: Yo pondría como válido `[A-Za-z]` y luego convertiría la salida con `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @cnbandicoot editado ^^

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster prefiero [0-9] para que solo utilice esos digitos y no otros digitos como no-arabigos o japoneses hehe

Comment: @lois6b En realidad, **sí** puedes usar `\d` en lugar de `[0-9]` y siempre serán *esos* dígitos, incluso si tienes la bandera `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` *activada*. :P Otra historia sería utilizar `\p{Digit}`, ¡naturalmente!

Comment: @PaulVargas gracias por la info! pero ya que no estamos en [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) pues no me importa usar mas bytes xDDD (y ademas lo considero mas *visible*, que se ve lo que representa))

Comment: El modificador [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS o (?U)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) cambia el comportamiento de `\d`. Ejemplo: http://rextester.com/BBX82177

Comment: @Mariano Efectivamente. Con `(?U)`, `\d` se comporta como `\p{IsDigit}`. ¡Esa bandera lo cambia todo!

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tendrías un método para generar una matrícula válida:

```
private static String generaMatricula()
  {
    //Letras válidas para matrícula
    char[] array = {'B', 'C',
                    'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 
                    'M', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 
                    'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    String matricula = "";

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int ale = (int)(rnd.nextDouble() * array.length); //Aleatorio para la letra
      int ale2 = (int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 10); //Aleatorio entre 0-9
      if (i>3) {
        matricula += array[ale];
      } else {
        matricula +=  ale2;
      }
    }

    return matricula;

  }
```

Pudiendo llamarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
System.out.println(generaMatricula());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me refería a esto :)

Comment: por que no tienes vocales?

Comment: @lois6b La DGT eliminó las vocales de las matrículas para evitar acrósticos, (como IBM, ETA, etc.), nombres propios (ANA, EVA, etc.) y palabras malsonantes (ANO, PEO, etc.)

Comment: @cnbandicoot ya pero segun sus normas... xD en su ejemplo hay una A

Comment: @cnbandicoot - quizás no se debería asumir que es una matrícula española

Comment: Añadiría el comentario de que las letras del array permiten generar una matrícula válida en España. Otros países van a requerir unas letras diferentes.

Comment: @Orici pero os vais a temas que no son hhaha la usuaria no pide matriculas españolas/europeas/marcianas... pide 4 digitos y 3 letras xD

Comment: @lois6b, mi comentario se refiere a esta solución en concreto.

Comment: @orici ya y por eso digo "os vais" tu, el de la respuesta esta y la respuesta de abajo xDD

Answer (score 1):

Quieres comprobar si la matricula es valida? Para eso podemos crear un método que compruebe mediante expresiones regulares si la matricula es correcta.

Hay que tener en cuenta que existe el formato europeo y el Español antiguo, para ello podemos utilizar el método siguiente que comprueba ambos casos o, si sólo te interesa el método europeo, puedes hacer un `return false` en el else del primer `if`

```
    final String consonantes = "BCDFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    final Pattern patternES = Pattern.compile("(["+consonantes+"]{1,2})(\\d{4})(["+consonantes+"]{0,2})");
    final Pattern patternEU = Pattern.compile("(\d{4})(["+consonantes+"]{3})");
    boolean checkMatricula(String matricula){
            matricula = matricula.toUpperCase(); 
            Matcher eu = patternEU.matcher(string);
            if(eu.groupCount()>1){
                 return true;
            }else {
                Matcher es = patternES.matcher(string);
                if(es.groupCount()>1){
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
           }
    }
```

Aqui tambien puedes utilizar el matcher para devolver los grupos que hay, en el caso de ES tenemos el grupo 0 (toda la matricula), el 1 (primeras letras), el 2 (numeros) y el 3 (ultimas letras) mientras que el EU tenemos el 0 (toda la matricula), 1 (numeros) y 2 (letras)

Comment: Hola Soteck, me parece genial tu respuesta teniendo en cuenta las matriculas reales. pero no el ejemplo que puso la usuaria.

Comment: Que rapido eres! Jaja le di a publicar sin haber terminado la revisión de la respuesta, edito explicación

Comment: @Mariano yo no veo nada "claramente" el usuario ha hecho una pregunta de validación de formato de matricula y le he propuesto una solución para el estándar europeo y español.

Comment: @soteck "estará compuesta por 4 números consecutivos seguido de 3 letras también consecutivas, sin espacios en blanco entre números y letras"