# ¿Cómo volver a un método principal?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un método que controla el acceso de una matricula(1111AAA).

El problema es que detecta que una matricula no es valida y no vuelve a pedir ese método por pantalla.

Es decir continua pidiendo datos que no tendría que pedir, solamente los tiene que pedir si es `true`. En un `if/else`, puse el nombre del método `this.muestraMenuPrincipal()` y lo único que conseguí es que se parara la ejecución del programa.

```
public void muestraMenuPrincipal() {

    int introduceUnaOpcion = 1;

    while (introduceUnaOpcion == 1 || introduceUnaOpcion == 2) {
        System.out.println("1. Añadir vehículo");
        System.out.println("2. Obtiener el precio alquiler");
        System.out.println("3. EXIT");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        introduceUnaOpcion = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        switch (introduceUnaOpcion) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Introduce una Matricula:");
                String matricula = scanner.nextLine();
                comprobarMatricula(matricula);

                if (true) {
                    muestraMenuAnyadirVehiculo(matricula);

                } else if (false) {
                    muestraMenuPrincipal();
                    System.out.println("Intentalo de nuevo");
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Introduce una Matricula:");
                matricula = scanner.nextLine();
                comprobarMatricula(matricula);
                if (true) {

                    System.out.println("Introduce los Días:");
                    int numDias = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    muestraResultadoDeObtenerPrecioAlquiler(matricula, numDias);

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Intentalo de nuevo, no has introducido una matrícula correcta");

                }

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Has pulsado EXIT. ");

            default:
                System.out.println("Hasta la próxima :) ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `comprobarMatricula()` retorna un boolean?

Comment: @IvanBotero Si, retorna true o false. No lo he incluido aquí porque el método va bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método que comprueba la matrícula debe regresar un true o un false entonces gurda el valor en una variable.

```
        boolean matriculaValida = comprobarMatricula(matricula);
```

y despues haces las validaciones...

```
        if (matriculaValida) {
                muestraMenuAnyadirVehiculo(matricula);

         } else {
                System.out.println("Intentalo de nuevo");
                muestraMenuPrincipal();    
         }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona. Al principio pensaba que el boolean se tenia que poner en el método que comprueba las matriculas.

Comment: @bpico deberias arreglar tus preguntas cerradas o en espera, sobre todo si tu pregunta cerrada está relacionada con esta, como mi codigo de [`comprobarMatricula`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48117/15855)

Answer (score 1):

```
 comprobarMatricula(matricula);

 if (true) {
    muestraMenuAnyadirVehiculo(matricula);

 } else if (false) {
    muestraMenuPrincipal();
    System.out.println("Intentalo de nuevo");
 }

 //..

 if (true) {
 //..
```

Creo que basicamente es por que usas el `true/false` *palabra reservada* por todo el codigo.

Quizas estabas haciendo pruebas y se te paso el borrarlo, creo que tienes que comparar algo asi:

```
 if (comprobarMatricula()) {
     muestraMenuAnyadirVehiculo(matricula);

 } else {

     muestraMenuPrincipal();
     System.out.println("Intentalo de nuevo");
 }
```

o asiginarlo a una variable y despues comparalo con el if:

```
..//
boolean temp = comprobarMatricula();

if (temp) {
..//
```

p.d: ajustar a true o false segun devuelva